# How to insert a multidimensional array in a database using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on a eCommerce app in laravel. I want to save shopping cart values order and order details tables when the customer clicks checkout button. One order has many order details. I can insert order values: **customerid, orderdate,shipdate,orderamount……**
But as I have mentioned, one order have many orderdetails. This is my order details table:

```
**Id 
ordereid
product_id
price
quantity
price
amount**
```

Each order have many products as so:

```
Array ( [productids] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 11 [2] => 7 [3] => 1 ) [quantity] => Array ( [0] => 2[1]=>1[2]=>3) [price] => Array ( [0] => 750.00 [1] => 456.00 [2] => 200.00 [3] => 700.00 ) [amount] => Array ( [0] => 1500 [1] => 456 [2] => 600 [3] => 1400 ) )
```

This is what I have done and am getting      Array to string conversion exception

```
        for($i=0; $i < count($product); $i++)
        {
 $order_details =new Order_detail;  
    $order_details->order_id = $orders->id;        
    $order_details->product_id=$product['product_id'][$i];        
    $order_details->quantity=$product['quantity'][$i];    
    $order_details->unit_price=$product['price'][$i];        
    $order_details->amount=$product[amount][$i];

    $order_details->save();

       }
```

I have also tried to wrap each sub-array in foreach loop but only a single raw is inserted in the order details
For example if the customer order shopping cart has three products, three rows should be inserted into the order details with:

```
    Id  
    ordered
    productid
    quantity
    price    
   amount
```

Any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I'd do in this situation.

### Step 1: grab the objects from the array

```
$order_details = [];
for($i= 0; $i < count($product); $i++){
    $order_details[] = [
        'order_id' => $orders->id,
        'product_id' => $product['product_id'][$i],
        'quantity' => $product['quantity'][$i],
        'unit_price' => $product['price'][$i],
        'amount' => $product['amount'][$i],
    ];
}
```

### Step 2: Insert into table

```
\DB::table('order_details')->insert($order_details);
```

That's all you would need,
more on the insert method can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#inserts)

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I how I am getting a syntax error at foreach($i= 0; syntax error, unexpected ';'.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it's a for statement, not foreach, I've modified my answer