# Insert array of arrays in Lumen with Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

The POST request I'm sending looks like this:

```
{ "array1":
    [
        {"title":"my blogADD","description":"myblogdescriptionADD","status":1},
        {"title":"my blogUPDATEDADD","description":"myblogdescriptionUPDATEDADD","status":1},
        {"title":"my blog33ADD","description":"myblogdescription33ADD","status":1}
    ]
}
```

Its JSON format, headers have been set. 
The controller code which gets the request looks like this:

```
    public function create(Request $request){



  $this->validate($request, [
    'array1' => 'present|array',
    'array1.*.title' => 'required',
    'array1.*.description' => 'required'
  ]);

  $data = $request->getContent();

  $data = json_decode($data, true);
  //dd($data);
  Article::insert($data);

}
```

Now, I've looked into multiple questions and answers on SO on this problem, and the findings are somehow contradictory. 
`Model::insert()` shall be able to insert multiple rows in ONE call. 
However, as you can see, this hasn't worked for me so far. 
`Model::create()` is only able to create one new row, but I found solutions which use loops to iterate over the arrays. I would very very much like to avoid such a solution, unless someone can FOR CERTAIN tell me that there is no other, simple solution. Because I very much believe that there must be one.

When I input the json_decoded ARRAY  then I get the response that an Array to String conversion is hindering the process. 
When I input the mere JSON-String, then I get the error:

```
"Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, string given, called in E:\LumenTut\firstTut\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1350"
```

Well, here are two links to SO posts which, in my opinion, basically dealt with the same problem. But somehow it seems they could solve it and I can't, so I wonder what I am missing:

[How to insert a multidimensional array in a database using laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499001/how-to-insert-a-multidimensional-array-in-a-database-using-laravel)

[laravel 5.6 bulk inserting json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861486/laravel-5-6-bulk-inserting-json-data)

For completeness, here is the full Code of ArticleController.php:

EDIT:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use Validator;
use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    //

    public function showAllArticles(){
      return response()->json(Article::get(['title', 'description', 'status'])); // ::get([]) spezifiziert die zu referenzierenden Attribute
                                                                                // ::all() referenziert alle Attribute einer Tabelle/Relation
    }

    public function showOneArticle($id){
      return response()->json(Article::find($id));
    }


    public function create(Request $request){



      $this->validate($request, [
        'array1' => 'present|array',
        'array1.*.title' => 'required',
        'array1.*.description' => 'required'
      ]);

      $data = $request->getContent();

      //$data = json_decode($data, true);
      //dd($data);
      Article::insert($data);

    }

    public function update($id, Request $request){

      $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
      ]);

      $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
      $article->update($request->all());
      return response()->json($article, 200);
    }

    public function delete($id, Request $request){

      Article::findOrFail($id)->delete();
      return response('Deleted Successfully', 200);
    }

    public function resetRecords(Request $request){
      Article::where('id', '>', 2)->delete();
    }

}
```

Comment: use `Article::insert($data['array1']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, it feels like you are trying to push `array1` directly in your table, whereas you need to push the content of it so maybe try like this, in your controller code:

```
$requestData = $request->all();//this will give you an array with key array1
$data = $requestData['array1'];//this will give you data you want to insert  
Article::insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error. You are not passing an array. You can change the `$data` with

```
$data = $request->all();
```

`$request->all()` returns the data from the post in array.

You can rewrite your create method with the following.

```
public function create(Request $request){

$request->validate([
    'array1' => 'present|array',
    'array1.*.title' => 'required',
    'array1.*.description' => 'required'
  ]);

  $data = $request->all();

  Article::insert($data['array1']);

}
```